# Playing (non library) Apple Music content - request fails

Tags: ios, swift, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpmediaquery, apple-musickit

I'm trying to play an album, using the following code…

```
let predicate = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: "1459938538", forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumPersistentID)
let iCloudPredicate = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: true, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyIsCloudItem)
let query = MPMediaQuery.albums()
query.filterPredicates = [predicate, iCloudPredicate]

let mp = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer
mp.setQueue(with: query)
mp.play()
```

But it's failing with

> `[SDKPlayback] -[MPMusicPlayerController prepareToPlay] timeout`
>
> `[MediaRemote] MRC <MPCPlayerPath: route=<MPAVEndpointRoute: 0x280f1a280 name=iPhone uid=LOCAL> origin=iPhoneID bundleID=com.apple.MediaPlayer.RemotePlayerService playerID=MPMusicPlayerApplicationController>: Undo optimistic state [failed] command=Play error=Error Domain=MPCPlayerRequestErrorDomain Code=1000 "Failed to send command 0 (MRMediaRemoteCommandHandlerStatus = 1)" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Failed to send command 0 (MRMediaRemoteCommandHandlerStatus = 1), MPCPlayerErrorKeyMediaRemoteCommandHandlerStatus=1}`
>
> `[SDKPlayback] -[MPMusicPlayerController play] completed error: Error Domain=MPCPlayerRequestErrorDomain Code=1000 "Failed to send command 0" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Failed to send command 0, NSUnderlyingError=0x28344c810 {Error Domain=MPCPlayerRequestErrorDomain Code=1000 "Failed to send command 0 (MRMediaRemoteCommandHandlerStatus = 1)" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Failed to send command 0 (MRMediaRemoteCommandHandlerStatus = 1), MPCPlayerErrorKeyMediaRemoteCommandHandlerStatus=1}}}`

• If I remove the predicates, it'll play local albums OK.

• `SKCloudServiceController.requestAuthorization` is `.authorized`

• The device has both `.musicCatalogPlayback` and `.addToCloudMusicLibrary` capabilities.

• `1459938538` seems to be a valid id (it's for the latest Madonna album - https://music.apple.com/gb/album/madame-x-deluxe/1459938538)

*Any hints as to how to play an album that's not in my library?*

Comment: Did anyone find an answer to this? I am also facing a similar problem. Could it potentially be a problem on Apple's end?

Comment: has anyone found an anwser to this???

Answer (score 3):

MPMediaQuery is only for Library items. You would need to use the web Apple Music search API to get store IDs to use in setting the queue.